# Switch statement in php switches to a specific page

Tags: switch-statement

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="?id=action">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="?id=adventure">Adventure</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php
$id = (isset($_GET['id'])); set the value
    switch($id) {
        case 'actiune':include('/actiune/index.php');//first page
        break;
        case 'aventura':include('/aventura/index.php');//second page
        break;
    }
?>
```

It takes me to `/action/index.php` when i access adventure Why?
Please I need a bit of help

Answer (score 1):

Because you're switching on `true/false` here, as the result of [**isset**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) - which is always boolean value - is assigned to $id directly. This line should be rewritten as...

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
```

... where `''` can be actually replaced with that default value.

In fact, you can redirect user at the very moment when you find that `$_GET['id']` *is* empty, then analyze it's different values with `switch`. Like this:

```
if (! isset($_GET['id'])) { ... redirection ... }
switch ($_GET['id']) {
  case 'first': ...; break;
  case 'second': ...; break;
  default: ...;
}
```

Comment: I get a Notice: Undefined index: id in ... on line ... in the main page

Comment: I get a Notice: Undefined index: id in ... on line ... in the main page